# Putting Ubuntu on a Tablet Without USB

Tags: system-installation

I recently purchased an ASUS VivoTab Windows 8.1 tablet and, being the Linux enthusiast that I am, decided to install Ubuntu on it. Unfortunately, there are no USB or DVD drives, so I don't know what I'm supposed to install Ubuntu off of. I've already tried to format a MicroSD like an Ubuntu Live USB, but I can't seem to get the BIOS to let me boot off of the MicroSD. Any suggestions? I just need to install Ubuntu without using any kind of external drives. Alternately, I'm up for suggestions on the possibility of creating a Live MicroSD. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Micro USB to USB cable/OTG should do the trick, plug the USB drive into it with Ubuntu or other distro 'burnt' onto it and it should be able to boot from it. (You may need to do some trickery with the bootloader, I'd go to the XDA page if it has one to see about that)

Comment: no it will not.